# ¿Como capturar los eventos clics de forma personalizadas y enviarlos a Google Analytics en Vue3 y Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, vue3, google-analytics

Contexto: Estoy creando una aplicación con Ionic Framework 6 y Vue3. Necesito capturar los eventos del usuario. Ya estoy capturando el evento page_view entre otros. Estoy usando la librería NPM Vue-gtag.

Problema: Necesito capturar el evento clic a los botones promocionales del menú principal y enviar los datos de a qué botón se le dio clic. Entre los eventos recomendados por google en su [documentación](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/events?hl=es-419) no veo un evento clic que pueda usar para eso.

¿Se debe crear ese evento, por ejemplo 'clic_user' desde algún lugar en Google Analytics o Tag Manager? O ¿simplemente envío deliberadamente ese evento desde la app aunque no exista?